# More concise way to return null if list is empty

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I currently have some Jetpack Compose code similar to this:

```
val filteredList: List<String> = someList.filter { // some condition }
someState.value = if(filteredList.isNotEmpty()) filteredList else null
```

I filter a list using some condition, then set some state equal to that filtered list. However, if the filtered list is empty, I want the state to be set to null.

This code works, but I'm wondering if there is a more concise way to do this in Kotlin? I've tried playing around with the [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html), but I couldn't figure out how to return the null value when the filtered list was empty.

Comment: Your simple if-statement to change it to null seems plenty concise to me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more concise way would be to use `ifEmpty`, which returns a default value (in this case you'd want null) if the list is empty or else the list itself;

```
someState.value = filteredList.ifEmpty { null }
```

[A Kotlin Playground to play with](https://pl.kotl.in/X4YFmoztQ)

Comment: Link to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/if-empty.html). Looks like this was added in Kotlin 1.3, which is why some of us might not be aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [takeIf()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html) extension:

```kotlin
someList.filter { ... }.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
```